# Nexus behind a proxy

Tags: java, maven, proxy, nexus

I'm trying to install Nexus (the repository manager for Maven) in a machine behind a proxy. When I execute the server it tries to connect to the default repositories (https://repository.apache.org:443, https://repo1.maven.org:443 and https://nexus.codehaus.org:443) but it fails with a "network is unreachable" message (because of the proxy, I assume).

I tried adding additional JVM parameters to the jsw/config/wrapper.conf file to configure the proxy but it doesn't seem to work:

```
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.104.1.7
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dhttps.proxyHost=10.104.1.7
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: Since using proxies is not that uncommon for server applications I'd assume there is a special configuration for this. Those system properties most likely are not used, although I don't know Nexus administration that well (I could tell you for Artifactory though ;) ).

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure whether 8080 would be the correct port for https. Depending on the type of proxy the port might be 3128, 8443 etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a section in the Nexus Admin UI to configure proxy settings. It is located under Administration --> Server. See section 6.1.5 of the [Nexus Documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/configxn-sect-customizing-server.html).

Comment: Oh, wow. I feel so stupid now searching for config files and stuff when it was so simple... Thank so much David!

Comment: In Nexus OSS 3.5 this settings are under *Administration* -> *System* -> *HTTP*

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works if the Nexus application is already running and you are then trying to configure the proxy. I had to install Nexus on a machine without internet connection. During activation of license it tries to contact licensing.sonatype.com for which you will either need a direct internet connection or will need to ssh port forward it through another open to internet box. This little nuance gave me a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

```
>nexus.exe /run -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.104.1.7 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```